# SwiftUI ForEach of dictionary identified issue

Tags: swiftui

Using the given code below I try to iterate over the dictionary `wordList` which fails with the issue `Instance method 'identified(by:)' requires that '(key: Int, value: [String : String])' conform to 'Hashable'`.

So my guess is that I have either to apply the protocol `Hashable` somehow to the `Int` of the dictionary or there may be another solution which concerns the usage of `.identified(by:)`

Thank you very much for the help!

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var wordOrder = ["DE", "EN"]

    let wordList: [Int: [String: String]] = [
        0: [
            "DE": "Hallo Welt",
            "EN": "hello world"
        ],
        1: [
            "DE": "Tschüss",
            "EN": "goodbye"
        ],
        2: [
            "DE": "vielleicht",
            "EN": "maybe"
        ]
    ]

    var body: some View {
        Group {
            NavigationView {
                List() {
                    ForEach(wordList.identified(by: \.self)) { wordListEntry in
                        let lang1 = wordListEntry[wordOrder[0]]
                        let lang2 = wordListEntry[wordOrder[1]]
                        WordRow(lang1, lang2)
                    }
                }
                .navigationBarTitle(Text("Alle Wörter"))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SwiftUI iterating through dictionary with ForEach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56675532/swiftui-iterating-through-dictionary-with-foreach)

Comment: Not necessarily. I have checked the other question as well and that shows a viable approach. But that answer suggests creating an array for the keys and an array for the values. I am sure there might be solution for the question presented above which does not require those "sidesteps".

Comment: But how do you overcome the fact that a `Dictionary` is unordered, yet you are trying to catch when the array is reordered? If all `Hashable` does is "identify" the unique array element, you already have it with the Dictionary key! No matter what, you'll need *at least* one array for the `List()` order.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like you have a misunderstanding. Based on the code you posted, I guess you think that iterating over a dictionary iterates over the values in the dictionary. But that is not how dictionary iteration works.

When you iterate over a dictionary, you receive **pairs**. Each pair contains one key and the corresponding value from the dictionary. In your code, `wordListEntry`'s type is `(key: Int, value: [String: String])`, a pair whose first element is `key` of type `Int` and whose second element is `value` of type `[String: String]`.

I think you want to just iterate over the dictionary's keys, and then look up the corresponding values inside the `ForEach` body, like this:

```
ForEach(wordList.keys.sorted().identified(by: \.self)) { key in
    let lang1 = wordListEntry[wordOrder[0]]
    let lang2 = wordListEntry[wordOrder[1]]
    return WordRow(lang1, lang2)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is the way to go :)

Comment: A little further question: I noticed that you removed the variables inside the ForEach loop. My code also fails due to this because it seems that is not possible to use a var inside. Is there a workaround?

Comment: I thought `ForEach` used `@ViewBuilder`, which (as of Xcode 11 beta 2) doesn't allow local variables. However, I was wrong. But since the closure is not a single expression, you have to explicitly use the `return` statement. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Oh, thats a serious limitation right now. Hopefully this will be improved soon. Thank you for updating your answer!

Comment: Can you pls help me out on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56814962/map-value-in-particular-key-in-array-of-dictionary

Answer (score 0):

Updated for latest swift UI:

```
    ForEach(wordList.keys.sorted(), id: \.self) { key in
    let lang1 = wordListEntry[wordOrder[0]]
    let lang2 = wordListEntry[wordOrder[1]]
    return WordRow(lang1, lang2)
}
```