# create arraylist objects automatically on Swift

Tags: swift, algorithm, arraylist

I have a List that I want to divide according to atributes that I want to get.
For example. I if have this list I want to create 3 different lists using a main list.

```
  var companiesf = [
    Directory(directoryId: 1, fullname: "Jose Luis", company: "A"), 
    Directory(directoryId: 2, fullname: "Fernando", company: "A"), 
    Directory(directoryId: 3, fullname: "Maria", company: "B"), 
    Directory(directoryId: 4, fullname: "Rodrigo", company: "B"),
    Directory(directoryId: 5, fullname: "Miguel", company: "C")
  ]
```

Finally, I want to get this result

```
 var listA = [
     Directory(directoryId: 1, fullname: "Jose Luis", company: "A"), 
     Directory(directoryId: 2, fullname: "Fernando", company: "A")
   ]


   var listB = [
    Directory(directoryId: 3, fullname: "Maria", company: "B"), 
    Directory(directoryId: 4, fullname: "Rodrigo", company: "B")
   ]


   var listC = [
    Directory(directoryId: 5, fullname: "Miguel", company: "C")
   ]
```

but I don't know how to create array objects automatically

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your company arrays by creating a grouped dictionary

```
let groupedByCompany = Dictionary(grouping: companiesf, by: {$0.company})
```

and then create your arrays from it

```
let listA = grouped["A", default: []]
let listB = grouped["B", default: []]
let listC = grouped["C", default: []]
```

another option is to use `filter`

```
let listA = companiesf.filter {$0.company == "A"}
let listB = companiesf.filter {$0.company == "B"}
let listC = companiesf.filter {$0.company == "C"}
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how can I read "groupedByCompany" in a Foreach?

Comment: Do you mean like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56675532/swiftui-iterating-through-dictionary-with-foreach)