# Swift "Unable to infer complex closure return type; add explicit type to disambiguate" because of a dictionary

Tags: swift

I have this following dictionary:

```
@State var ustasList: Dictionary<Usta, String> = [Usta: String]()
```

And this view:

```
        ZStack(alignment: .top){
                DropDown(defaultText: self.chosenUsta, font: self.fontStartAndButton, expand: false, options: self.ustaTypes){ opt in
                    print(self.ustasList)
                }
                    .padding([.top, .leading, .trailing])
                .zIndex(2)
            List{
                ForEach(self.ustasList.sorted(by: <), id: \.self){ item,typ in
                    Text(item)
                 }
            }
         }
```

However this code gives me the following error:  `Unable to infer complex closure return type; add explicit type to disambiguate`.I tried to change trhe ForEach line to

```
ForEach(self.ustaTypes, id: \.self){ item in
```

Where ustaTypes is a simple one-dimensional string array and it worked properly. So why isn't it working with a dictionary?

Comment: You are trying to ForEach a Dictionary. According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56675532/swiftui-iterating-through-dictionary-with-foreach this does not work. Errors in SwiftUI are still often missleading and this could be the cause.